# How to add Backfire performance test with Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there any specific way or documentation on Blackfire performance test integration with Gitlab so that every commit will be verified before the merge.

Note: I have referred this doc already: https://blackfire.io/docs/integrations/git/gitlab